# About EarthQuake?

Tags: waves, earthquake

As you know in Nepal many aftershocks are coming and earthquake is related to physics as earthquake is also a longitudinal waves . I have some series of question as well as my thoughts about it?

1. Here People says at this day large earthquake is coming like in April 26-27 bla bla bla .. should we believe them ?
   ->No, But people says that plates are unbalanced there is many chance that very large earthquake can come due to balancing of plates.
2. Is it necessary for plates to be balanced after earthquake has come?
3. Geo Physicist here said no large earth quake will come after first earthquake and everybody started living in houses but again large earthquake came ?? So should we believe these geo physicist? Why they were wrong ?
4. Is there scale rather than Richter scale for measurement of earthquake?
5. Some people say this earthquake is 7.8 Richter sclae America says 7.9 scale (arbitrary values for now) ? To whom should we believe ?
6. Aftershocks are coming everyday .. And in april 25 about 5 Richter scale aftershock came so should we worry about it? when after shock is going to end?

Comment: Might [earthscience.se] be better suited for these questions?

Comment: @KyleKanos yes it might be .

Comment: There is absolutely no correlation between the date 26 and Earthquakes. I've seen that one go around a lot. Just sensationalized stuff cooked up by bored people.

Comment: The simple fact is that physics can't predict everything. If it could, all physicists would be winning the lottery all the time and none of us would be allowed to ever enter a casino. Earthquakes are among those kinds of events that can not be predicted effectively. Anybody who gives you detailed predictions can be dismissed for now. The variations in Richter scale estimates are within the usual measurement errors for these things and 0.1 difference really doesn't matter. One thing physics can predict but not prevent: earthquakes don't kill people, old structures do when they cave in.

Comment: This question is better suited for a different StackExchange page.